# Why does my HVAC system cause brownouts when it comes on?

Tags: electrical, hvac

After being away from home for a good while (10+ hours, doesn’t happen often since I WFH) I get temporary blackouts when my compressor fan kicks on. This is central AC, not a window unit. The blackouts only happen in the area of the house physically closest to the condenser fan - the remainder of the house is not impacted.

I thought the issue would be the capacitor - sure enough, after a test, the capacitor was only at about 75% of rating when spec is +/- 6%. I got that replaced, seemed things were ok.

I left for a week, returned this evening, and the same issue happened. Because it had been less than a week since installing the capacitor, I find it difficult to believe it would have gone bad already, though I will check. What other problems could cause this?

Comment: How old is your HVAC compressor? Or might be on its last legs and starting excessive current at startup.

Comment: Installed in 2015 when the house was constructed. I hope it isn’t dying yet, but I suppose it could be.

Comment: Motors typically have a start up surge current that's greater than the run current.  This can cause a short term (less than 1 sec) low voltage condition until the motor is up to speed.

Comment: It sounds like a failing connection to me but I can only guess as I do not know how your wiring is layed out. I am assuming it is a window unit as you did not specify.

Comment: @SteveSh that’s true, but it is noticeably worse than it used to be - enough to turn off electronics now.

Comment: @Gil, I’ll edit - it isn’t a window unit, it’s a central hvac.

Comment: Is this a blackout (text) or brownout (title)? Big difference between the two. A blackout is "power goes 100% off to certain circuits" - I would find that highly unusual. A brownout is "voltage goes down (e.g., from 120V to 100V or less) to certain circuits" and can *easily* be caused by one circuit in the house drawing more power than designed, particularly if the total service size is relatively small. Why only some circuits? Many factors - panel/subpanel configuration, sensitivity of different types of equipment, etc. Pictures of your main panel and, if it is in a subpanel, the subpanel

Comment: powering the HVAC equipment might help. Also the nameplate ratings (and possibly other details - e.g., make/model) of the HVAC equipment.

Comment: Is it on a branch panel, normally I would expect it to effect the whole house, not about 1/2. Electrically they appear to be seperate. It could be a loose connection or wire that is not large enough to support part of the house. Another possibility is you are partially losing one of the main phases feeding the home.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact normally brown out, but occasionally it is a black out, or at least close enough to one that my tv resets like it does after a power outage and my batter backups in the office kicked on.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact it’s a 7.5 year old house w/ 200amp service, so I wouldn’t expect that to be the issue. I can get hvac specs tomorrow.

Comment: @Gil no branch panel, off main panel. I had an HVAC tech come out to check it out, he checked the wires, it seemed ok on his end. Maybe could be losing one of the main phases.